# Workaround for the lack of default template parameters in visual c++ 2012

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

I have a class like this:

```
template <class Object = NullObject>
class MyClass : OptimizedStorage<Object> {
...

public:
    //Cannot do this in Visual studio 2012
    template <class Object2 = Object,
              class = enable_if<!is_same<Object2, NullObject>::value>>
    Object & get() const {
        return this->object_;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know:

1. A workaround for having this interface.
2. Some other workaround that even if it makes things a bit more dirty, still allows me to `get()` my underlying object when it exists.

Regards

Comment: You may use `std::enable_if` on the return type.

Comment: BTW, second template argument should be `class = typename enable_if<!is_same<Object2, NullObject>::value>::type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround is to write a wrapper function which just calls the template. For example:

```
private:
    template<typename ENABLER>
    Object& get_()
    {
        return this->object_;
    }

    template<typename Object2>
    Object& get_()
    {
        return get_<typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Object2,NullObject>::value>::type>();
    }

public:
    //Overload for default Object template parameter:
    Object& get()
    {
        return get_<Object>();
    }
```

Of course the compiler is cappable of inline all the wrappings, so performance is not a concern here.

*Note that I have dopped the `const` qualifier: You are returning a reference to internal data, that getters cannot/shouldn't be `const`.*

Comment: This won't work since I need to enable or disable the function given the template parameter. The frontend function must exist only in some cases and I cannot figure out how to solve that.

Comment: Seems to not compile in my case. It gets confused about two versions of `get_` function.

Comment: With a small change it worked. I named the most internal function to get2_

Comment: @GermanDiago sorry for the mistakes, I have just written the solution from my head too fast, I had no time enough to check it completely for correctness. I will update the answer later for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
template <class Object = NullObject>
class MyClass {
    Object object_;

    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, NullObject>::value, Object &>::type
    get_() { return this->object_; }
public:
    Object& get() { return get_<Object>(); }
};
```

or you may specialize your struct (that may require some copy/paste :/ ):

```
template <class Object = NullObject>
class MyClass {
    Object object_;
public:
    Object& get() { return this->object_; }
};

template <>
class MyClass<NullObject> {
public:
    // No get function.
};
```

Comment: I knew of this solution (partial specialization). But I hate to duplicate code. When you modify it, if you forget anything it's fragile.